# read a date from a text file and put in a object date

Tags: java, date

I have to read a Date from a file and the date is written on this file in this way: `dd/MM//yy` but when the I read I obtain values totally different. For example: `17/11/10` became `Mon Jan 04 00:00:00 CET 2010`. The value is different.why?

This is the code I use:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YY");
Date dat=sdf.parse(reader.readLine());
```

Comment: I get a parseException error changing `MM` to `MMM`

Comment: Try editing your question to include what `reader.ReadLine()` returns. Perhaps it's not what you think it is.

Comment: Ok I resolved.I changed `YY` to `yy`.now works

Comment: While in 2011 it was obvious to choose `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, for anyone reading this question in 2017 or later, those classes are long outdated. Instead I recommend `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` from `java.time` (also known as JSR-310). The modern classes are generally much nicer to work with, and `LocalDate` models a date without time-of-day, which is what you need here.

Answer (score 3):

The placeholder for year is `yy`, not `YY`. Don't know why it gives this result, though.

Comment: Part of the explanation is that capital `YY` is for week-based year (only useful with a week number).

Answer (score 0):

Can you include your actual code in the question because I doubt its `dd/MM//yy` and `dd/MM/YY` is invalid.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
String text = "17/11/10";
System.out.println(sdf.parse(text));
```

prints

```
Wed Nov 17 00:00:00 GMT 2010
```