# Reading DATE type from text file

Tags: java, date, arraylist

I have a text file which looks like this

```
2017-06-14  7932
2017-06-15  10092
2017-06-16  7626
2017-06-17  7613
2017-06-18  11072
2017-06-19  8286
2017-06-20  9293
```

I am trying to store the values in an `ArrayList`.

My Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sample2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        List<Date> l1 = new ArrayList<Date>();
        List<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader("t1.txt"));

        while (s.hasNext()) {
         l1.add(s.nextInt());      !!!!-----Error Line-----!!!!!!!!
         l2.add(s.nextInt());
        }


        s.close();

        System.out.println(l1);
        System.out.println(l2);;
    }
}
```

I get the Following Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
>   The method add(int, Date) in the type List is not
>   applicable for the arguments (int)
>     at Sample2.main(Sample2.java:17)

How do I fix it?

Comment: You're trying to insert an int into a list of Dates.

Comment: Side comment, if you use Java 8 you should use a `List<LocalDate>` instead of a `List<Date>`

Comment: Do you know how to convert your input into a Date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read a date from a text file and put in a object date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436600/read-a-date-from-a-text-file-and-put-in-a-object-date)

Comment: This is probably a better dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30388616/2988730

Comment: J.N, Is there a method that adds a date type to a list? Thanks

Comment: @MadPhysicist.. Is there a method that adds a date type to a list? Thanks

Comment: @Chid. `add` will do it for you, but you aren't adding a Date, you are trying to add an integer.

Comment: @Chid The method to add something to a list is `add`, but the problem in your code is that you declared a list of dates (`List<Date>`)  and tried to add an `int` (`l1.add(s.nextInt())`). You must first parse the input `2017-06-14` to a date and then add it to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for an `int` by using the `nextInt()` method.

"else" `s.next()` will return a `String`.

This will fix your error:

```
while (s.hasNext()) {
   if (s.hasNextInt()) {
       int myInt = s.nextInt();
       System.out.println(myInt);
   } else {
       String dateAsString = s.next();
       System.out.println(dateAsString);
   }
}
```

When I run this code, I get:

```
2017-06-14
7932
2017-06-15
10092
2017-06-16
7626
2017-06-17
7613
2017-06-18
11072
2017-06-19
8286
2017-06-20
9293
```

You will have to convert your date string to a `localDate()` or `Date()`

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. Create a small class to hold the date and the `int` that belong together. Why? See Jon Skeet’s [Anti-pattern: parallel collections](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/).
2. Skip the outdated `Date` class and use the modern `LocalDate` instead. It models a date without time-of-day, which is exactly what you need here. It also parses your dates right out of the box with no need for an explicit format, so it’s very convenient for your specific purpose.

Below I have just lumped the code together in one class, you will probably want a design with more classes. I will leave that to you.

```
public class Sample2 {

    private LocalDate date;
    private int value2;

    public Sample2(LocalDate date, int value2) {
        this.date = date;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\nSample2 [date=" + date + ", value2=" + value2 + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        List<Sample2> l = new ArrayList<>();

        Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader("t1.txt"));

        while (s.hasNext()) {
            l.add(new Sample2(LocalDate.parse(s.next()), s.nextInt()));
        }

        s.close();

        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

The program prints

```
[
Sample2 [date=2017-06-14, value2=7932], 
Sample2 [date=2017-06-15, value2=10092], 
Sample2 [date=2017-06-16, value2=7626], 
Sample2 [date=2017-06-17, value2=7613], 
Sample2 [date=2017-06-18, value2=11072], 
Sample2 [date=2017-06-19, value2=8286], 
Sample2 [date=2017-06-20, value2=9293]]
```

I will also leave to you to add getters (you may not need setters) and to find better variable names. You know what the numbers mean.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with below code

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sample2 {
    private static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    List<Date> l1 = new ArrayList<Date>();
    List<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader("t1.txt"));

    while (s.hasNext()) {
        l1.add(getDate(s.next()));
        l2.add(s.nextInt());
    }

    s.close();
    System.out.println(l1);
    System.out.println(l2);
}

private static Date getDate(String next) {
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = dateFormat.parse(next);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
```

}

Comment: Better formatting and a word of explanation would be nice, but you have the right idea. Why is there an unformatted trailing brace?

Comment: @Ramachandra Reddy, Thanks. but the list is stored in the "Wed Jun 14 00:00:00 EDT 2017" format instead of yyyy-MM-DD.

Comment: Yes. The date will be stored in that format only. If you want to retain the "yyyy-MM-DD" format, you have to declare list l1  as List<String> instead of  List<Date>

Comment: @Chid That's the result of [`Date.toString()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--). Actually, a [date has no format](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/)

Comment: While parsing the dates into something that is meant for holding dates is a good idea, please don’t teach the young ones the long outdated classes `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Today we have so much better: I recommend the modern Java date and time API known as `java.time` or JSR-310. Start with the [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Then use `LocalDate`. Its `parse` method even parses the dates in the file without any explicit formatter.